# On Deriving time dilation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

I want to derive the time dilation formula in special relativity *using that the separation between two world points is Lorentz invariant*.

I define the following:

1. Inertial frame $S'$ moving at speed $v$ relative to frame $S$.
2. At a point in space in $S'$, a process of duration $\Delta t'$ takes place.

**My attempt**

I want to find $\Delta t$. The seperation between the world points is:

$\Delta\vec{s}=(\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z,ic\Delta t)$

or

$d\vec{s}=(dx,dy,dz,ic dt)$. The norm is:

$d s^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-c^2dt^2$.

From this I can get another Lorentz invariant:

> $$d\tau^2=-\frac{ds^2}{c^2}=dt^2-\frac{1}{c^2}(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$$

If the process is in rest in $S'$, then:

$d\tau=dt$.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

The separation is invariant, therefore we have:

$dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-c^2dt^2 = dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2-c^2dt'^2$

Now, the un-primed coordinates are not moving, so $dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 = 0$.

Now divide by $-c^2dt'^2$ on each side, you get:

$dt^2/dt'^2$ = $1- (dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2)/c^2dt'^2$

so:

$dt^2/dt'^2$ = $1- v^2/c^2$

then:

$dt'^2/dt^2 = 1/(1- v^2/c^2)$

$dt'^2 = dt^2/(1- v^2/c^2)$

$dt' = dt/\sqrt{1- v^2/c^2}$

I just realized you wanted dt, not dt', but you can easily see that:
$dt = dt'\sqrt{1- v^2/c^2}$